# Visual Studio Code - Remote debugging without ptvsd

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug python code inside docker containers.

Visual Studio Code can do this but I have to install ptvsd on the remote machine and edit the code to import it and start listening.

In PyCharm Pro I don't have to install any libraries.

Is there a workaround or a method to remote debug python code in VSC without having to install ptvsd on the remote environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the Python extension for VS Code does not send ptvsd on your behalf over an SSH connection like PyCharm does. But we are [working on a solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/79) to make remote debugging smoother.